# How to use predicates in an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I use [thirtyfour](https://github.com/stevepryde/thirtyfour) in my Rust script, and it uses [tokio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio) as the async runtime.

When I use `find` in a `Vec::iter`, it doesn't work as I expect:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> WebDriverResult<()> {
    let dropdown = driver.find_element(By::Tag("select")).await?;
    dropdown
        .find_elements(By::Tag("option"))
        .await?
        .iter()
        .find(|&&x| x.text() == book_time.date) // Error, x.text() return a futures::Future type while book_time.date return a &str.
        .click()
        .await?;
}
```

After I tried [Ibraheem Ahmed's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65925331/155423), I met more errors:

```rust
let dropdown = driver.find_element(By::Tag("select")).await?;
let elements = dropdown.find_elements(By::Tag("option")).await?;
let stream = stream::iter(elements);
let elements = stream.filter(|x| async move { x.text().await.unwrap() == target_date });
```

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src\main.rs:125:38
    |
125 |     let elements = stream.filter(|x| async move { x.text().await.unwrap() == target_date });
    |                                   -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
    |                                   ||
    |                                   |return type of closure is impl futures::Future
    |                                   has type `&'1 thirtyfour::WebElement<'_>`
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good thread on [the Rust User's Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-filter-an-async-stream/40565) that covers a similar question.

I tried the code snippets below by modifying the [thirtyfour tokio_async example](https://github.com/stevepryde/thirtyfour/blob/21d21bae923742b3763b7a76378aed378889b1fa/examples/tokio_async.rs).  I didn't have your full context, so I created an example that found a link based on its text on the wikipedia.org home page.

1. [`filter_map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.filter_map).

   ```rust
   let target_value = "Terms of Use";
   let found_elements: Vec<_> = stream
       .filter_map(|x| async move {
           if let Ok(text) = x.text().await {
               if text == target_value {
                   println!("found");
                   return Some(x);
               }
           }
           None
       })
       .collect()
       .await;
   ```
2. `while` loop (which is probably not what you are after, but could be a simple solution if your logic fits easily inside)...

   ```rust
   while let Some(element) = stream.next().await {
       let text = element.text().await?;
       println!("link text result: {}", text);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Stream`, which is the asynchronous version of `Iterator`:

```
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

fn main() {
    // ...
    let stream = stream::iter(elements).await?;
    let elements = stream
        .filter(|x| async move { x.text().await.as_deref() == Ok(book_time.date) })
        .next()
        .click()
        .await?;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...and that is the problem: the compiler will complain about "await is only allowed inside async function". Seems the closure inside the *find* does not regard as an async function.

Comment: oh lol, I totally missed that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I still met some errors. I've updated the original post, can you help me out?